# Send an email with a link to open document in browser to simultaneously edit a document

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, co-authoring

I'm very new to SharePoint so some help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to create a workflow for the following process:

A user moves a document into a document library with several other users listed as "Reviewer(s)". I need an email or task to go out to all the Reviewers letting them know that they have a document to review. I would like for the email to include a link to the edit document in browser screen so that numerous people can edit at the same time. Once each user as finished making any changes they want, I'd like for them to sign-off on it somehow. Once all users have sign-off, an email or notification needs to be sent back to the "Created By" user - the original person who put the document into the library.

Currently, I have it sending an email to all Reviewers, but the best I can do is send a link to the Word document, opened in Word. This doesn't allow the extent of co-authoring I was hoping for. It also seems to make a copy of the document, instead of creating a new version for the same document. I need all the changes to show on the same document so the creator can review them all and harmonize the changes.

Attached is my current library setup. Please let me know if you need any additional information!

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered setting up alerts for all the reviewers? that will save you time instead of creating a workflow.

Also, opening up the document in Office web application by default is possible by turning off the feature at site collection level called 'open document in client application'.

One last suggestion is that power point, word and one note can use co-authoring even from the client application. Only excel needs the browser excel app to be able to offer co-authoring.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution without code is to use **alerts** to adjust it to send an email if the item added or changed, from the above ribbon of your list but you should configure outgoing mail.

[image]

also, You can use Event receiver with the item was updated event as mentioned [here](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-in-SharePoint-2013-and-SharePoint-2010) to send an email if item updated.